# How to reload current tab from within a chrome extension popup.html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, page-refresh

I am trying to click on a button to refresh the current page from within a chrome extension.

(NOTE: The reason is because I loaded a script and I needed the page to refresh because presently I just have a disclaimer"you need to refresh the page for it to work", but I would like to remove this disclaimer and just have it done automatically).

I can't figure it out. Here is my code I am trying to refresh the page. If you know a way to eliminate this code and just use an onclick that would be great too, but I tried `onclick="location.reload();"` but it doesn't work because it isn't fetching the actual tab but just the popup page.

***background.html***

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (activeTab) {
    var newURL = toggleDevMode(activeTab.url);
    chrome.tabs.update({
        url: refresh
    });
});
```

***refresh.js***

```
document.getElementById("mydivtoclicky").onclick = function() {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        tabId = tab.id;

        // send a request to the background page to store a new tabId
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:"new tabid", tabid:tabId});
    });
};

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:"refresh"});
```

***popup.html***

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../refresh.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mydivtoclicky">REFRESH PAGE</div>
</body>
```

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To refresh the page use [chrome.tabs.update](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) with the tab's url.

refresh.js:

```
document.getElementById("mydivtoclicky").onclick = function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: tabs[0].url});
    });
};
```

Comment: I don't need the other stuff? Just this?

Comment: Ok thanks, but it didn't work.  You know that I'm clicking this from within the chrome extension popup?

Comment: How can I say not being there? Use the debugger: right click the popup and `Inspect popup`, open the Source tab, find your js file, set a breakpoint inside the onclick handler, then click your `mydivtoclicky`.

Comment: Yes I had the tabs permission. But, it's not working still. When I click on the div, the page is not reloaded. I verified that refresh.js is being loaded into the popup, but it is not reloading the page.

Comment: debugging says this in the debugging screen for refresh.js: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`

Comment: Ahem. Well of course. The script is referenced in `<HEAD>` so it executes before the popup html page is loaded so you either have to use a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener or put the `<script>` tag just before the closing `</body>` tag. Please remove all these comments, they have nothing to do with the original question nor the answer.

Comment: Perfect!! Okay so instead of putting in the popup head tag I placed it AFTER the div that needs to be clicked. Now it works! YAY!! Thank you :) p.s. I think these comments are relevant. They are good for people coming in to read and debug just like I am doing. :) Will accept the answer as soon as I can. Edit: accepted answer, will upvote as soon as I have 15 rep so I can.

Comment: Well, those are basic gimmicks in js development, but okay, you have a point.

Comment: In order to enable `chrome.tabs.update`, need `"permissions": [
          "tabs"
        ],` in `manifest.json`

Answer (score 16):

Assume you want to refresh the tab the user is using in the current Chrome window from the extension background runtime, you can use the following example in background.html/background.js.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[0].id);
});
```

More about [chrome.tabs.reload](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-reload).

Answer (score 9):

My Chrome extension correctly reloads the active tab using chrome.tabs.reload() with all defaults. Very simple. The popup itself stays open.

In popup.js...

```
function reloadMainTab() {
    chrome.tabs.reload();
}
document.getElementById('reloadBtn').addEventListener('click', reloadMainTab);
```

---

You will need to have the `tabs` permission in your `manifest.json`.

Comment: This looked the simplest. As opposed to what you might think, this only reloaded the tab I am currently on, rather than all tabs in the browser, which is exactly what I desired.

Comment: This is the best answer.